# does WCF's NetTCPBinding supports Socks Proxy?

Tags: wcf, proxy, nettcpbinding

I've got a client/server WCF application I want to deploy in a corporate environement.

They usually don't allow direct Internet connections, so I must use their SOCKS proxy.

Is it possible to use the netTcpBinding channel over a socks proxy?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, only for the HTTP binding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, definitely not ([link to my own post on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/755c21fe-41c5-4267-9b32-df57d3c1838e))